# Web Service Needs To Accept Unspecified Arguments

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have a web service that is used to manage various "events" that occur in a live telephony system.

The method I am working on really needs to accept two arguments.

1. The type of event
2. Some arguments

The "some arguments" is a number of key/value pairs.

The web service is going to be called from other languages - not just .NET languages.

What should my method signature look like...

```
public bool Notify(string eventType, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string> arguments)
```

Or...

```
public bool Notify(string eventType, IDictionary<string, string> arguments)
```

Or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stay away from interfaces when defining data contracts. Maybe something like this:

```
public bool Notify(string eventType, KeyValuePair<string, string>[] arguments)
{

}
```

Or define a custom class:

```
public class Argument
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public bool Notify(string eventType, Argument[] arguments)
{

}
```